# how to equate unigram tfidf to 0 when bigram of related unigram is nonzero?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, n-gram

I am doing sentiment analysis of movie review using python with scikit-learn and nltk. i want to equate elements related to unigram to 0 (when they are having opposite polarity) when a bigram/ trigram related to those unigram are non zero.

for example:

`movie is not bad`

than feature vector is `['movie' 'is' 'not' 'bad' 'movie is' 'is not' 'not bad']=[3 3 1 1 4 2 4]`

but i want `[3 3 0 0 4 2 4]` instead.

code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

import math
#######################Reading Training Review Phrases and Sentiments###################################

train_list = []
train_sentiment = []
with open('sentences.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
for sentence in content:
    train_list.append(sentence.rstrip('\n').split("\t")[0])
    train_sentiment.append(sentence.rstrip('\n').split("\t")[1])

#######################Number of phrases in each class###################################

ex_pos = pos = neu = neg = ex_neg = 0
ex_pos_phrases = pos_phrases = neu_phrases = neg_phrases = ex_neg_phrases = []

with open('ex_pos.txt', 'r') as ex_posF:
    ex_pos_phrases = ex_posF.readlines()
    ex_pos = len(ex_pos_phrases)
with open('pos.txt', 'r') as posF:
    pos_phrases = posF.readlines()
    pos = len(pos_phrases)
with open('neu.txt', 'r') as neuF:
    neu_phrases = neuF.readlines()
    neu = len(neu_phrases)
with open('neg.txt', 'r') as negF:
    neg_phrases = negF.readlines()
    neg = len(neg_phrases)
with open('ex_neg.txt', 'r') as ex_negF:
    ex_neg_phrases = ex_negF.readlines()
    ex_neg = len(ex_neg_phrases)

print(str(ex_neg) + "," + str(neg) + "," + str(neu) + "," + str(pos) + "," + str(ex_pos))

####################### Getting unique Words ###################################

unique_words = []
model = TfidfVectorizer(input=train_list)
train_tfidf = model.fit_transform(train_list)
unique_words = model.get_feature_names()

print("##### Word sentiment matrix ####")
########################## Word sentiment matrix ########################################

word_sentiment = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(len(unique_words)) ]
wordcount = 0
for word in unique_words:
    count = 0
    for review in ex_neg_phrases:
        review_words = review.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
        for review_word in review_words:
            if review_word == word:
                count += 1
                break
    word_sentiment[wordcount][0] = count
    count = 0
    for review in neg_phrases:
        review_words = review.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
        for review_word in review_words:
            if review_word == word:
                count += 1
                break
    word_sentiment[wordcount][1] = count
    count = 0
    for review in neu_phrases:
        review_words = review.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
        for review_word in review_words:
            if review_word == word:
                count += 1
                break
    word_sentiment[wordcount][2] = count
    count = 0
    for review in ex_pos_phrases:
        review_words = review.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
        for review_word in review_words:
            if review_word == word:
                count += 1
                break
    word_sentiment[wordcount][4] = count
    count = 0
    for review in pos_phrases:
        review_words = review.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
        for review_word in review_words:
            if review_word == word:
                count += 1
                break
    word_sentiment[wordcount][3] = count
    wordcount += 1
print("###The Training feature matrix###")
#################################The feature matrix#######################################
feature_matrix = [[0 for x in range(len(unique_words))] for x in range(len(train_list))]
print(len(feature_matrix))
print(len(feature_matrix[0]))

wordcount = 0
for unique_word in unique_words:
    phrasecount = 0
    ep = p = nu = en = n = 0
    if word_sentiment[wordcount][4] != 0:
        ep = .35 * math.log(word_sentiment[wordcount][4]/ex_pos)
    if word_sentiment[wordcount][3] != 0:
        p = .15 * math.log(word_sentiment[wordcount][3]/pos)
    if word_sentiment[wordcount][2] != 0:
        nu = 1 * math.log(word_sentiment[wordcount][2]/neu)
    if word_sentiment[wordcount][0] != 0:
        en = -.35 * math.log(word_sentiment[wordcount][0]/ex_neg)
    if word_sentiment[wordcount][1] != 0:
        n = -.15 * math.log(word_sentiment[wordcount][1]/neg)

    for phrase in train_list:
        words = phrase.split(" ")
        docwordcount = 0
        for word in words:
            if word == unique_word:
                docwordcount += 1
        tfidf = (docwordcount * ep) + (docwordcount * p) + (docwordcount * nu) + (docwordcount * en) + (docwordcount * n)
        feature_matrix[phrasecount][wordcount] = tfidf
        phrasecount += 1

    wordcount += 1

print("###The test feature matrix###")

test_list=[]
test_phraseid =[]
with open('sentences_test.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
for sentence in content:
    test_list.append(sentence.rstrip('\n').split("\t")[0])
    test_phraseid.append(sentence.rstrip('\n').split("\t")[1])

wordcount = 0
test_tfidf = [[0 for x in range(len(unique_words))] for x in range(len(test_list))]

for unique_word in unique_words:
    phrasecount = 0
    ep = p = nu = en = n = 0
    if word_sentiment[wordcount][4] != 0:
        ep = .35 * math.log(word_sentiment[wordcount][4]/ex_pos)
    if word_sentiment[wordcount][3] != 0:
        p = .15 * math.log(word_sentiment[wordcount][3]/pos)
    if word_sentiment[wordcount][2] != 0:
        nu = 1 * math.log(word_sentiment[wordcount][2]/neu)
    if word_sentiment[wordcount][0] != 0:
        en = -.35 * math.log(word_sentiment[wordcount][0]/ex_neg)
    if word_sentiment[wordcount][1] != 0:
        n = -.15 * math.log(word_sentiment[wordcount][1]/neg)

    for phrase in test_list:
        words = phrase.split(" ")
        docwordcount = 0
        for word in words:
            if word == unique_word:
                docwordcount += 1
        tfidf = (docwordcount * ep) + (docwordcount * p) + (docwordcount * nu) + (docwordcount * en) + (docwordcount * n)
        test_tfidf[phrasecount][wordcount] = tfidf
        phrasecount += 1
    wordcount += 1

print("###The Linear SVC ###")

self = LinearSVC()
self = LinearSVC.fit(self, feature_matrix, train_sentiment)
test_sentiment = LinearSVC.predict(self, test_tfidf)

with open('output_deltatfidf.csv', 'w') as fil:
    fil.write("PhraseId,Sentiment\n")
    for x in range(0, len(test_sentiment)):
        fil.write(test_phraseid[x] + "," + test_sentiment[x] + "\n")
```

Comment: Could you show us the actual code you have?

Comment: thnx for quick reply... i want to replace element of all unigrams of corresponding bigrams/trigrams in a 'feature_matrix' if sentence contains bigrams/trigrams. 

ex: if 'not bad' is there in the sentence then 'not' and 'bad' related elements should be zero. if only 'not' or only 'bad' is there in the sentence then related elements should be non-zero